# Windows Server 2012: Powershell is not recognizing NuGet

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, nuget, windows-server-2012

I am facing a situation where nuget.exe is not being recognized by Powershell in Windows Server 2012. I am pretty sure that the environment variable has been correctly set. Yet I am getting the following error:

```
nuget : The term 'nuget' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ nuget
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nuget:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am getting the same error even if I go to the directory where `nuget.exe` is present and execute `nuget`.

Windows CMD is showing `nuget is not a recognized command`, but it's working fine if I execute `nuget` inside a directory where `nuget.exe` is present.

Am I making a mistake in setting up environment variable for nuget? Please help :)

**Note**: I am new to dotnet tech ecosystem.

Comment: In PowerShell, if you navigate to the folder of an executable, you must prefix the name with ".\" for it to run.  For example: `C:\Nuget> .\nuget.exe`

Comment: @boxdog it worked. Thank you for helping me and others who find themselves stuck in this situation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like a lot of Unix systems, Powershell doesn't include current directory in the path. One needs to either use full path or explicitly include current directory.

Try `.\nuget.exe` in Nuget's directory.

As explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-6),

> As a security feature, PowerShell does not run executable (native)
>   commands, including PowerShell scripts, unless the command is located
>   in a path that is listed in the Path environment variable $env:path or
>   unless you specify the path to the script file.

Comment: @AdityaKrishnakant Alternatively, ensure the path to `nuget.exe` is included in the environment's `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your path variable should be a Semi-colon separated list of paths containing your directories: On one of my Server 2012 boxes it looks like this:

> %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\TShell\TShell\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\

which is a bit long and awkward. You should append your path to NuGet to this string and save it.

From `Windows Explorer`, right click on `This PC` => `Properties`. Locate `Advanced system settings` on the the left hand Panel. Choose the `Advanced` tab. Click on the `Environment Variables` button on the bottom right. Scroll the window down until you find the `Path` variable.

I usually copy and paste it to/from a text editor for ease of use.